# Switch between activities on click menu item

Tags: android, android-activity

i' ve added a listener on an action bar' item , when i click it i switch to another activity. This works but when i perform this action i can notice that i  receive errors on my logcat, can someone explain me what's is happening?

i change activities with this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 2:
            // go to activity2
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            // dispose the current activity while launching the next intent
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

and my log cat shows:

```
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306): Activity  has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42bc61e8 that was originally added here
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tweetmeetup.logic.main.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42bc61e8 that was originally added here
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:397)
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-16 11:12:58.523: E/WindowManager(6306):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:556)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
```

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

The solution is to call dismiss() on the Dialog you created  before exiting the Activity, e.g. in onPause(). All windows&dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.

Try this: (Based on your comments)

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 2:
            // go to activity2
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            // dispose the current activity while launching the next intent
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: no i' m not. I want to shut down the activity after clicking the item.

Comment: i'm not creating any dialog, i have only an activity with an action bar on which i've added some sub menu item, when one of these is selected i switch activity.